# Using EditText to pass data from fragment to fragment

Tags: java, android

I use EditText to enter an integer value and Integer.parse it in the first fragment and use an interface to send the value to the second fragment. I applied the ViewPager2 as well. I am not that adept in using View Pager as this is my first time in using it. Please post code if possible.

So my questions are

1. Where did i go wrong in my code for running it? (The error lies in

   ```
   SM.sendData(Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString()));
   ```

   which i don't get what is the mistake)
2. Is there another way to transfer the value using another method such as Bundle?

First Fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentFirstBinding binding;
    SendMessage SM;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final EditText text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SM.sendData(Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString()));
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                       .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    interface SendMessage {
        void sendData(int number);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            SM = (SendMessage) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Error in retrieving data. Please try again");
        }
    }

}
```

Second Fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSecondBinding binding;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.score_result);

        binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void displayReceivedData(int number)
    {
        textView.setText(number);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

View Pager Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Lifecycle behavior) {
        super(fm,behavior);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
        }
        assert fragment != null;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstFragment.SendMessage{

    ViewPager2 viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getLifecycle());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(int number) {
        SecondFragment secondFragment=new SecondFragment();
        SecondFragment f = (SecondFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(secondFragment));
        f.displayReceivedData(number);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_status) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a Java interface is one of the best and fast methods of passing data asynchronously. But you stated *The error lies in...*, then what the errors say though @Karla43?. Please consider adding the error message. You better optimize your interface in the way the it can be used between the fragments directly. Think of it like a producer - consumer where your first fragment is producer and the second one is consumer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass data between fragments and especially for navigation components we have something called as SafeArgs. Use the below link to consider which method you wish to try out, the android docs for this is self-explanatory.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Also since you specifically asked if bundles are possible, well yes it is.

```
// FirstFragment.class
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data", text1.getText().toString());
NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment,bundle);

// SecondFragment.class
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.score_result);
textView.setText(getArguments().getString("data"));
```

Comment: I am curious as to the val type. is it imported from this line of code 

`import lombok.val`

Comment: hi @Karla43, it was an oversight from my end. I use kotlin on a daily basis and that caused me to answer your question in kotlin instead of java. I have coverted the answer to java.